# Use of **kwargs in python hook __prepare__

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass

I am unable to understand from the python documentations how the kwargs for the hook `__prepare__` can be utilized.

> Once the class namespace has been populated by executing the class body, the class object is created by calling `metaclass(name, bases, namespace, **kwds)` (the additional keywords passed here are the same as those passed to **prepare**).

So does this mean after populating the class namespace, we can use these keyword arguments to add extra attributes available to the class? If yes then how and where can we pass values to this, so that it is populated with different attributes based on some condition as, afaik the call to `__prepare__` after the population of the class namespace should be implicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass keyword arguments to the metaclass constructor from a `class` statement. It's not really useful, except to impress people with the obscure features of Python you're familiar with.

The keywords are passed on to `__prepare__`, `__new__` and `__init__`, though if you only override `__new__`, neither `__init__` nor `__prepare__` will complain about unexpected extra arguments.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        print("Got keywords in __new__: {}".format(kwargs))
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)

    def __prepare__(name, bases, **kwargs):
        print("Got keywords in __prepare__: {}".format(kwargs))
        return {}

class Klass(metaclass=Meta, key1=1, key2="fred"):                   # keywords used here!!!!
    pass
```

You don't need to use `**kwargs` syntax to catch the arguments. You can name them explicitly if you prefer (though they can only be passed as keywords, not as positional arguments).

Comment: On Python 3.6+, the extra keywords are also passed down to the class' (not the metaclass'), `__init_subclass__`

Comment: @jsbueno: That's a good point. It's not just the class the keywords are defined in, but rather all its base class's implementations of `__init_subclass__`. I wonder if class keywords will become a more common thing, now that the machinery for using them has improved (and support for Python 2 where they don't exist is ending).